# Setting image as a background to a select tag

Tags: css

Here is the css part:

```
#selectTagId{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    background-image: url('images/img01.jpg');
    background-position: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The image path is correct. But the image isn't shown. Instead, the background is white? Ughhh how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it works with an absolute img path. See http://jsfiddle.net/9qf59/2/

Keep in Mind, that relative paths in css can lead to some odd effects. they are relative to the css file, not the document.

Comment: How do you mean it works? The image is pink, and the dropdown is white.

Comment: what do you mean by: "dropdown"? the down folded options or the select element itself?

Comment: @BastiagRang The select element whole, not just the arrow.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9qf59/6/ the whole element is covered with the nice pink background-image.

Comment: I think the problem is my computer. I saw the link from my colleague's PC and it was pink :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you apply this style to a div? if so, you must specify width and height of that div:

```
#selectTagId{
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  background-image: url('images/img01.jpg');
  background-position: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: No, there is no div. There is <td> however.

Comment: that doesnt answer his question and is wrong. he uses an select-element and there is no need for height and width.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to see the comment above. I just see the question.